# Why does JUnit test pass when invoked directly but fail when invoked using Maven?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit

I encountered a bug today where a test was failing when run via Maven : "mvn test" and passing when running directly via jUnit.

Here is code in question :

```
public class TestAssert {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assert("test" == "test2");
    }

}
```

The above code passes a Junit test but when the test is executed using Maven I received this error :

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(TestAssert)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at TestAssert.test(TestAssert.java:15)
```

When does it pass when using jUnit directly and fail when using Maven ?

Comment: Have you tried "test".equals("test") ?

Comment: @Guito ive updated question should read assert("test" == "test2");

Comment: I tried to execute it from my IDE and it failed too: java.lang.AssertionError. Don't you expect it to fail? :) - Edit: What's directly with junit?

Comment: should fail on both.have you checked -ea flag ? In general it is better to use assertTrue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assert` is evaluated or not depending on whether you use the `-ea` (enable assert) flag. So the best guess is that your default configuration when running the test directly has `-ea` enabled but maven doesn't.

The proper way to test that condition with junit is:

```
assertTrue("test" == "test2");
```

or:

```
assertSame("test", "test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit tests passed in Eclipse/GGTS, but failed when running by "mvn test" with the error info: "**Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError**"

The cause could be just the opposite with the answer earlier here.
Try disabling enableAssertions for surefile and it works for me after 2 days' digging. (it's true by default!)

```html
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
      <configuration>
        <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
      </configuration>
```